# Missing trade data for difference in differences model

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, missing-data, model, difference-in-difference

I have missing monthly trade data for my dependent variable in the DiD model. Are there any methods to compute the missing data, so it does not lead to a bias? Also, for many products, there are no monthly trade data for the time period, should I just ignore these products?

Comment: How much “missingness” are we talking about here? Also, is “product” a covariate with no time variation at all? A little more detail will be very helpful.

Comment: @ThomasBilach I have around 60% of the trade data missing and product is a time-varying covariate. The policy implemented in a specific period affects the product at a given time which impacts the export/import of certain products but most of the monthly trade data is missing for these products.